# Some SVG elements disappear when hiding adjacent divs

Tags: html, jquery, svg, svg-filters, jquery-svg

I have a project where I've created a number of divs which each contain an svg gauge. Each gauge is multi-layered and when displayed, it looks great.  Its a complex gauge, so I wont include the code, but the structure is:

```
`    <div>  (filtered at this level with css display)
      <svg>
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <g>
        </g> (multiple g tags)
      </svg>
    </div>`
```

I use jQuery and a dropdown to filter the view where I literally only change the div from "display:inline-block" to "display:none".  The divs which are meant to be hidden are, but the showing divs with their child svgs are missing layers (entire g tags).  When I change the filter setting back to all of them, the layers return.  As you can see in the code, its very simple and the un-filter (id = -1) results in the same condition as the shown divs in a filtered view.

```
`   function filterCell(id) {
    $('.theseGauges').each(function () {
        let filteredList = CellM.filter(a => a.cellNameId == id);
        if (parseInt(id) == -1) {
            $(this).css({ 'display': "inline-block" });
        } else {          
            let a = filteredList.findIndex(b => b.machineId == $(this).attr("mid"));
            if (a != -1) {
                $(this).css({ 'display': "inline-block" });
            } else {
                $(this).css({ 'display': 'none' });
            }
        }
      })  
    }`
```

To add to the strangeness, I also have the ability to filter these gauges by location.  This works perfectly in a filtered and unfiltered state (in this case, thisOption == 1 is all locations).

```
`    $('#filterMachineLocation').change(function (e) {
        let thisOption = $(this).val();
        $('.theseGauges').each(function () {
            if (parseInt(thisOption) == 1) {
                $(this).css({ 'display': "inline-block" });
            } else if (parseInt($(this).attr('loc')) != thisOption) {
                $(this).css({ 'display': 'none' });
            } else {
                $(this).css({ 'display': "inline-block" });
            }
        });`
```

I've tried this with the same result in Chrome and Edge.  I opened the dev tools and copied the div HTML in both the complete and incomplete states and ran it through WinMerge.  They are the same.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: I suspect that you are using things from the hiden svg elements. Something you may have inside the <defs>.  Try putting the defs inside a different svg element with width="0" height="0" and position:absolute

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @enxaneta Good thought, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: In this case you may need to take advice from @Marc and create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Here is a fiddle where the same behavior is present:  https://jsfiddle.net/BTremelling/23amxzL5/13/

Comment: I just realized that everything I'm losing is some sort of gradient, so my defs are disappearing.  Why and why do they come back?

Answer (score 0):

@enxaneta was right on with the answer.  The real problem was that I was loading the defs into each svg and creating duplicate id's for my gradients. It didn't work the first time because I was still iterating and making duplicate ids.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Duplicate IDs are bad - that's for sure. But the **main problem** is actually, if the first element containing the gradient is hidden via **display none** – the gradients won't be applied. But the browser still refers to it. 
Unlike in css (last rule overrides previous) – in svg **the first definition will be applied** e.g. a gradient, clip-path, mask etc. Unfortunately it doesn't matter if the first definition can't be applied or not (when hidden via display:none). Hiding the first element via `position:absolute; width:0;wheight:0` would retain the gradient.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Your comment helped me more than the actual answer in tracking down my issue, thank you! Maybe add it as a separate answer if other Googlers are looking?